# Interpreting NMDS environmental correlations in the context of spatial and temporal autocorrelation

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, autocorrelation, multidimensional-scaling, environmental-data

**Do I need to account for autocorrelation when assessing correlations of environmental variables on an NMDS (nonmetric multidimensional scaling) ordination of species data?** If so, how?

Data + setup:

- I've constructed an NMDS ordination from a Bray-Curtis distance matrix calculated from relativized abundances (basal areas) of trees. Samples include ~40 forested plots that have been resampled 13-15 times each.
- I also have ~60 environmental variables (soil, topography, etc.) that were measured from each plot in the last sampling year. Many variables relate and/or are correlated to one another.

Goal:

- I want to determine if any of my environmental variables explain the NMDS structure and if so to what degree.

Attempt:

- I opted to use `vf()` from the [ecodist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecodist/ecodist.pdf) package in R (though I know a lot of people use `envfit()` from the [`vegan`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vegan/vegan.pdf) package). - From the help page, `vf` provides the following:

  > matrix with the first 2 columns containing the scores for every
  > variable in each of the 2 dimensions of the ordination space. r is the maximum correlation of the
  > variable with the ordination space, and pval is the result of the permutation test.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Geographic coordinates (UTMN and UTME) are strongly correlated to my NMDS axes (i.e., they have significant large `r` values from vf output).

   - Does this impact my interpretation of my other environmental variables?

     - (e.g., if soil pH has a relatively large r=0.35 and p <0.05, I would consider it an important explanatory variable. However, in the context of the strongly/highly correlated geocoordinates, I'm wondering if my interpretation remains valid from these simple data output form `vf`).
   - Do I need to control for this spatial autocorrelation when interpreting the relationship of my other variables to the NMDS ordination axes? (If so, what is the procedure?)
2. Given that my samples are resampled (and therefore I have many samples representing each plot), I assume some degree of temporal autocorrelation is at play as well.

   - Since I only measured my environmental variables once, I think this is a moot point. (though possibly problematic on its own)
   - How do I address this if necessary?